# get current working directory in Lua

Tags: windows-xp, lua, getcwd

What's the Lua to get the current working directory on Windows XP SP3 (or to get the directory of the currently-running Lua file)? I prefer *not* to use [LuaFileSystem](http://keplerproject.github.com/luafilesystem/index.html).

I can't use `os.execute("cd")` because `os.execute` always starts from my home directory (and thus always yields `C:\Documents and Settings\username`).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Lua by default doesn't have a "native" way of supporting the concept of "current directory", or, in fact, the concept of "directory".

The proper way to get the current directory is using a library that provides folder support. There are several - I recommend [luafilesystem](http://keplerproject.github.io/luafilesystem/).

Once it is installed, you can get the current directory by executing:

```
lfs.currentdir()
```

This will work on windows, linux and mac.

Beware though that these external libraries usually involve some binary packages. Depending on your setup, you might have to compile it before being able to use it.

EDIT:

Note that when a file is included via `require`, then the expression `{...}[1]` returns the path used by the `require` directive. It is not exactly the path because:

- It uses dots to separate directories and supresses the `.lua` at the end of the file.
- It is relative to the path from which the lua process was initialized
- It depends on the configuration of [`package.path`](http://lua-users.org/wiki/PackagePath)

But if all you need is the "require-like path" of the file (maybe to require files next to it) then you can get it by doing this at the very beginning of the file:

```
local PATH = (...):match("(.+)%.[^%.]+$") or (...)
```

If a file called `baz.lua` is required with `require 'foo.bar.baz'`, then `PATH` will be `foo.bar`.

Comment: Thanks. Looks like I'll have to settle with LuaFS.

Answer (score 22):

maybe some ugly hack like

```
current_dir=io.popen"cd":read'*l'
```

Comment: This seems to have the same effect as `os.execute("cd")`.

Comment: nope, os.execute'cd' only prints the output, while the io.popen thing captures it, and puts it in the current_dir variable

Comment: Have to close the "popen" - maybe store the popen in a local and close it after the read. Otherwise this will leak handles.

Comment: @ArunR It will only "leak" handles temporarily until they're garbage collected. Try `print(io.popen("ls").__gc)`.

Comment: does not work for me on macOS with lua 5.4, it returns `nil`.

Answer (score 11):

You should be able to get the currently-running lua file path with:

```
debug.getinfo(1).short_src;
```

or

```
debug.getinfo(1).source;
```

and then the current directory with a regex:

```
string.gsub(debug.getinfo(1).short_src, "^(.+\\)[^\\]+$", "%1");
```

Edit: actually that only works if you're running your lua with the full path.
e.g.: "lua.exe C:\test\test.lua" and NOT "lua.exe test.lua"

Comment: In Linux I had to use `debug.getinfo(1).source` and change the regex to `string.gsub(debug.getinfo(1).source, "^@(.+/)[^/]+$", "%1")`.

Comment: For a lua newbie playing around with neovim config files, your answer is a saver! Thank you @GusE

Answer (score 6):

I haven't had time to test this, but have you tried [os.getenv](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-os.getenv) to read windows environment variables?

Windows has an environment variable for current directory: **%CD%**

```
os.getenv("CD")
```

**Edit:** Tested on Windows 7 and while other environment variables work (ie. %USERNAME% or %PROGRAMFILES%) the CD var returns nil

Comment: Yeah, I had tried getenv without any luck. I'm starting to think it's not possible without LuaFileSystem.

Comment: I was able to pass the %CD% variable to the script, might work depending on how you execute your scripts. I.E: C:\>lua5.1.exe test.lua %CD% (then the path is available as arg[1])

Comment: %CD% is not a process environment variable, it's provided by the shell, so it won't work

Comment: try `os.getenv("PWD")` on mac

Answer (score 2):

I tried all these answers but nothing worked. I tested the following script, and it works as expected.

```
io.popen("cd"):read()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [alien](http://alien.luaforge.net/) to call out to [GetCurrentDirectory in kernel32.dll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364934%28VS.85%29.aspx), but that's probably not what you're looking for.