# Lua os.getenv does not work in a batch file

Tags: lua, environment-variables

I have a little script to read my PATH and store in a file, which I would like to be scheduled to run daily.

```
path = os.getenv("PATH")
file_name = "C:\\temp.txt" 
file = io.open(file_name, "w")
file:write(path)
file:close()
```

If I run it from command line it works, but when I create batch file (I work on Windows XP) and double click it - the os.getenv("PATH") returns false. The batch file:

```
"C:\Program Files\Lua\5.1\lua" store_path.lua
```

I read in comments to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6032268/get-current-working-directory-in-lua) that it "is not a process environment variable, it's provided by the shell, so it won't work". And indeed, some other env variables (like username) work fine.

---

The two questions I have are:

1. Why the shell does not have access to the PATH? I thought it would
   make a copy of the environment (so only setting env variable would be a problem)?
2. What would be the best way to read the PATH in such a way that I can add
           it to a scheduler?

Comment: I can't reproduce your error.  Your script works fine for me on double-clicking bat-file.  WinXP.

Comment: If you are running a batch file any way why not just do "echo %PATH% > C:\temp.txt" in the batch file?

Comment: What is the exact text of the batch file you're using?

Comment: @JaneT: I used Lua to do a bit more in the script, like use current date in the file name. Which surely could be done with the Windows shell too :).

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff: I'd be really interested in the reason it baheves differently on your machine... For me it only works after adding 'cmd /c' before the command - as suggested in the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have the batch file run it from a shell so that you get shell variables:

```
cmd /c C:\path\to\lua myfile.lua
```