# Relative paths are not relative to where the script lives? Lua

Tags: module, lua, path

Suppose I have the following structure on my computer:

```
directory 
    a.lua
    subdirectory
        b.lua
```

and this Lua code:

```lua
-- a.lua
foo = "bar"

-- b.lua
dofile("../a.lua")
print(foo)
```

If I now run `lua b.lua` from directory, the relative path `"../a.lua"` is relative to directory, and the interpreter complains that b.lua does not exist. If I run the same command from within subdirectory, then the relative path `"../a.lua"` is relative to subdirectory, so it works.

My question: Why is it that relative paths are relative to where we execute the script, and how do I make it so that they are relative to where the script lives instead, like in the CJS `require`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [get current working directory in Lua](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6032268/get-current-working-directory-in-lua)

Comment: relative paths are relative to the current working directory. not the directory containing the current script file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code (Lua 5.2+ required) works from any directory

```
-- b.lua
local path = (({...})[2] or arg[0]):gsub("[^/]*$", "")
dofile(path.."../a.lua")
print(foo)
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution, although it would be best if you could find a solution that works for all versions of Lua 5.

Comment: @Nirvana - What is your Lua version?

Comment: I have Lua 5.4, but I am writing a package for others to use that needs to be compatible with older versions.